# Is there any way out to solve this import' node:js' error of flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am new to flutter. Tried every possible to resolve this including importing the file to removing the file. nothing worked and I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W26E8.png) am pissed off.

click on the text in blue to see the CODE

Answer (score 1):

`dart:js` is a web-only package. You simply can't use it for mobile apps. Hovering over the line in your code would have informed you about that

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: @RohanShahi not much you can do except for not using that import. Whatever it is you need it for you need to find an alternative. But by the looks of it (it's grey), you are not using that import anyway so maybe just remove the line